# Unable to format Powershell foreach output and attach it to email body and subject

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm scheduling script if windows scheduled task is disabled from the given list then send email to me with Taskname in email subject and Taskinfo in body.

But I am unable to format email body and add disabled task name in to subject.

**Please help me to format email body and add disabled task name to subject.**

Here is my script-

```
$tasknamelist= Import-Csv "C:\Documents\task.csv"

foreach ($task in $tasknamelist) {
 $service=Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$taskname" | select -ExpandProperty State | Out-String
    if ($task.State -eq "Disabled") {
    $Body ="$service is not running"
    }
else {

Write-Host "$Body Task is enabled" | Out-Null

}

} $Body
$From = "xxx@outlook.com"
$To = "xxx@outlook.com"
$Cc = "xxxx@outlook.com"
#$Attachment = "C:\temp\Some random file.txt"
$Subject = ""
$Body = "$Body"
$computer = $env:computername
$SMTPServer = "outlook.office365.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject "Task Scheduler is disabled on $computer" `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $cred
```

Comment: What's the use of three ending back ticks? You don't need to add them in line continuation.

Comment: it's added when formatting code when posting this question.

Comment: And the port parameter accepts int32 values not string.

Comment: Email part is working fine, only issue is Disabled task name and info not correctly coming in Body and subject.
From: <xxx@outlook.com>
Date: Wed, Dec 25, 2019 at 7:58 PM
Subject: Task Scheduler is disabled on DESKTOP-1 
To: <xxx@outlook.com>
Cc: <xxx@outlook.com>

Comment: The issue is the commas. You have to escape them by adding a back tick before it.

Comment: the issue is, disabled task name not coming in email subject and body..

if you can suggest the line of code which will add task name if it disabled and then email will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared $body as an empty vaiable after ending foreach loop. The fixed code is:

```
$tasknamelist = Import-Csv "C:\Documents\task.csv"

foreach ($task in $tasknamelist) {
 $service = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$taskname" | select -ExpandProperty State | Out-String
    if ($task.State -eq "Disabled") {
    $Body = "$service is not running"
    }
else {

Write-Host "$Body Task is enabled" | Out-Null

}

} 
$From = "xxx@outlook.com"
$To = "xxx@outlook.com"
$Cc = "xxxx@outlook.com"
#$Attachment = "C:\temp\Some random file.txt"
$Subject = ""
$computer = $env:computername
$SMTPServer = "outlook.office365.com"
$SMTPPort = 587
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject "Task Scheduler is disabled on $computer" `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential $cred
```

And you didn't add white space in declaring variable.

Comment: # Set the event IDs you want to check
$eventID1 = 'EventID1'
$eventID2 = 'EventID2'

# Set the start and end dates
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)
$endDate = Get-Date

# Create an empty array to store the results
$results = @()

Answer (score 0):

```
$tasknamelist= Import-Csv "C:\Documents\task.csv"

foreach ($task in $tasknamelist) 
{
    $service=Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task
    if ($service.State -eq "Disabled") 
    {
        $Body ="$service is not running"
        $From = "xxx@outlook.com"
        $To = "xxx@outlook.com"
        $Cc = "xxxx@outlook.com"
        $computer = $env:computername
        $Subject = $task + " disabled on " + $computer
        $SMTPServer = "outlook.office365.com"
        $SMTPPort = "587"
        Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $cred
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$Body Task is enabled" | Out-Null
    }
}
```